# Display excel file with Liuggio/Excelbundle and Symfony2

Tags: excel, symfony, twig, phpexcel

I just want to display a Excel file existing on my hardisk in a twig view.

I'm using Symfony[2.5] and "Liuggio/Excelbundle"

This trick works well but i want to add it in my view.

```
 public function newAction()
    {
        $filename = 'filename.xlsx';
        $reader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filename);
        $excel = $reader->load($filename);
        $writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, "HTML");

        $writer->generateStyles();
        $writer->generateSheetData();

// this doesnt work..
        return $this->render('MonextReportingBundle:Default:excel.html.twig', array(
            'excelHtml'=>$writer
    ));
```

And in my excel.html.twig :

```
{{ excelHtml | raw }}
```

Catchable fatal error: Object of class PHPExcel_Writer_HTML could not be converted to string

Thanks a lot guys ! Excuse my english..

Comment: Did you try `excelHtml.generateSheetData | raw`?

Comment: @Maerlyn it works great ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel's HTML writer has no toString(), that's why your attempt didn't work.

It has, however, a method called `generateSheetData` that seems to do what you want. Use it like this:

```
{{ excelHtml.generateSheetData | raw }}
```

Comment: Maerlyn, do you know how to set Max column ?

I want to display only 14 columns in my HTML table.

I dont know how to implement a Filter inside my newAction function..

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SimonDelaunay if you have a question, [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)